# c JNI call java function

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

My first function code in c jni is

```
void fun1()
{
   jmethodID java_fun = (*global_env)->GetMethodID(global_env,cls_Env, "test1", "()V");
   (*global_env)->CallVoidMethod(global_env,(*global_obj), java_fun);
}
```

And my second is

```
void fun2(int x)
{
   jmethodID java_fun = (*global_env)->GetMethodID(global_env,cls_Env, "test2", "([I)V");
   (*global_env)->CallVoidMethod(global_env,(*global_obj), java_fun,(int)x);
}
```

In my java side the code for first c function is

```
private void test1()
{
    System.out.printf("test1");
    callfunction();
}
void callfunction()
{
   System.out.printf("how i can get here??");

}
```

The first question is how can i get to callfunction() from C call?

Now the second java code for second c function is

```
public int var1;
private void test2(int x)
{
    System.out.printf("test2");
    var1=x;
}
```

The second question is how can i save my data from c side in java side?

Thanks

Comment: Why haven't you defined `jmethodID` for **callfunction()**?  It seems you were on the right track with **test2** method...

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in `fun2()`: it should read `GetMethodID(global_env, cls_Env, "test2", "(I)V");` (the **[** is wrong).

If you want to call `callfunction()` from C directly, use

```
GetMethodID(global_env, cls_Env, "callfunction", "()V");
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to enable auto complete/Intellisense for eclipse while using NDK in android

Comment: @james, it is supposed to work out-of-the-box; there are many little quirks that may go wrong, and they certainly will at some point. Deleting the project from your Eclipse and importing it anew sometimes solves the problems for some time.

Comment: How u do coding when it comes to NDK? because the NDK C apis are not properly documented. At least provide some steps to enable AutoComplete. This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618201/how-to-enable-auto-complete-intellisense-for-ndk-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

```
Q1:

void fun1()
{
   jmethodID java_fun = (*global_env)->GetMethodID(global_env, cls_Env, "test1", "()V");
   (*global_env)->CallVoidMethod(global_env, global_obj, java_fun);

}

Q2:
 void test2(int x)
{
    System.out.printf("test2");
    var1=x;
}

void fun2()
{
   int i = 2;
   jmethodID java_fun = (*global_env)->GetMethodID(global_env, cls, "test2", "(I)V");
   (*global_env)->CallVoidMethod(global_env, global_obj, java_fun, i);

}
```

Please check this [link](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)

Comment: When i call test2() and i try to print x Content i get result it work but line after that when i try to save this content its Crash

Comment: By the way the goal for all this was to pass a text buffer from JNI to JAVA side and print it with kind of opengles-text-printer libs that i found in google its seems to me more short way from use C libs to do the same thing